# True aproach for continious speech recognation with delphi

Tags: delphi, speech-recognition

I am trying to establish a system to catch the speech from continuous speaker.

Like this.

```
1- start recording
2- When you hear a sound start a trigger which detects -when that speech is ended-?
3- When 1-2 seconds silent happened fire that trigger and stop recording
4- analyze and recognize the recorded speech ( I have a component for that I dont do that by my self)
5- Start the system from the beginning
```

I tried some algorithms like measuring the sound levels of 2 secons with 100 ms intervals. Then sum them and get a value to check.
But because it was too complicated I couldn't achieve my aim what to do now?

Comment: To approach a problem: record a typical speech sound, open it in some wave editor, see how waveform is changing in time. Zoom in, zoom out, scroll back and forth, try to find patterns with your eyes. Formalize patterns - first as use-cases, then as formulas, then as functions and conditions in a program.

Comment: the end of this phrase is : then apply for a job in google team  I think :) . I am just amator programmer (with enough level of knowledge to do what I want) Yes I graphically see what is the shape of waves but I dont think I need that complex approach. I just need to detect a sound which is over a treshold

Comment: Understood. With the approach "sum them and get a value to check" - what exactly was complicated? It should have been something like (x1 + x2 + ... + xN) / N, isn't it?

Comment: what exactly was complicated? This is the exact question I ask myself :) here is the code on the timer (100 ms interval) to check whether there was sound or not

Comment: TForm1.isSpeechStartedTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
var

  i: integer;
begin
  TheLast1SecondsSoundValue := 0;
  for i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    TheLast1SecondsSoundValues[i] := TheLast1SecondsSoundValues[i + 1];
    TheLast1SecondsSoundValues[9] := round(isSpeechStartedALPMetersLastValue);
  end;

Comment: for i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    TheLast1SecondsSoundValue := TheLast1SecondsSoundValue + TheLast1SecondsSoundValues[i];
  end;

  if TheLast1SecondsSoundValue div 10 > 2500 then
  begin
    IsSpeechStarted:=true;
    for i := 0 to 9 do
    begin
      TheLast1SecondsSoundValues[i] := 0;
    end;

    isSpeechFinishedTimer.Enabled := true;
    // isSpeechStartedSLScope.
    isSpeechStartedALAudioIn.enabled:=false;
    isSpeechFinishedALAudioIn.enabled := true;
    isSpeechStartedTimer.enabled := false;

  end;
end;

Comment: The algorithm for calculating average volume seems to be fine. Does the condition "> 2500" fire at all? Do you stop isSpeechStartedTimer, when it is fired?

Comment: @user3057015, please don't add code in the comments as comments get do get deleted. code belongs in your question.

Comment: Does the condition "> 2500" fire at all? """""yes""""" Do you stop isSpeechStartedTimer, when it is fired? """""yes"""""